# Rate of convergence of $\left[ \left( \sum\limits_{i=j}^n {2i+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]$

Tags: analysis

I have
$$a_{n} = \left[   \left( \sum\limits_{i=j}^n {2i+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]$$
for some fixed $j\geq1$, where the square brackets are the fractional part.
Now I know 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = 1$$
as for $n\geq \frac{j^{2}}{2}:(n+1)^2-c_1=b_n\ge n^2+1$ for $c_1=j^2$,  where $b_n$ is the sum.
But now how fast is $a_n$ converging to $1$? Is the laurent series as good as you can get? ($1-c/(2n)+c/(2n^2)-...$)

Comment: $[\ ]$ is for integer parts, $\{\ \}$ for fractional parts.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n\geqslant\frac12j^2$, $$\sum_{i=j+1}^n(2i+1)=\sum_{i=j+1}^n(i+1)^2-i^2=(n+1)^2-j^2\in[n^2+1,(n+1)^2-1],$$ hence $$a_n=\left\{\sqrt{(n+1)^2-j^2}\right\}=\sqrt{(n+1)^2-j^2}-n=\frac{(n+1)^2-j^2-n^2}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2-j^2}+n},$$
that is, $$a_n=2\frac{1-\frac{j^2-1}{2n}}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac2n-\frac{j^2-1}{n^2}}}=1-\frac{j^2}{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right).$$